# Connecting 2 different networks (routing / Gateway)

Tags: routing, gateway

I have a basic question about connecting two networks, and the routing / dns settings required:

- Network A (company, 2008 R2 Environment) is a Domain-Network, containing it's own dhcp, dcs, Internet-Gateway, etc.
- Network B (home, 2012 Environment) is a Domain-Network (different domain), containing it's own dhcp, dcs Internet-Gateway, etc.

Both Networks use a different (local) IP-Range, which is quite helpfull I assume.

Currently i'm in progress of building a new home, where the company is visible "Bee-Line", which would theoretically allow to connect both sites through some directional-wifi connection. (Devices for this purpose support up to 50km, but it's only as little as 2km)

So, I'm quite familiar with dns-setups, but never done a real "routing". What would be required to "teach" every network how to connect to devices on the other network - i.e. use a second gateway/router to connect to a certain domain?)

ps.: I'm seeking for a solution that - if possible - can be auto-delivered in the respective network through GPO / DNS or DHCP-Settings. "Local Configurations" of clients should be avoided.

pps.: I want to keep the networks isolated (own DC / DHCP etc.), only routing requests between hosts on either network

Example:
[image]

best,
dognose

Comment: Should be easy; you need each network's default gateway device to have a single route entry added, saying "the other subnet is accessible via (IP of the local end of the wifi link). The specifics will depend on exactly how the networks and the wifi link are configured.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler But how will be DNS-resolution be able to work? The routing-information is about IPs i'd say - how does a device in "domain1" know, that it should use the SECOND Gateway, AND query the dns server of "domain2" for the exact destination? (I have full control over both sites, so configuration stuff is no issue.)

Comment: I mean, the first step for "clients" would be: resole the IP on the other site. (Then, a routing table comes in to resolve the routing, imho)

Comment: The device does not know it should use the second gateway; it tries to talk to a device outside its subnet, sends the traffic to its default gateway. That has a route which says "ah this is not internet traffic, it's remote site traffic", and *the gateway router* routes the traffic via the route to the remote site.

Comment: Once you have routing working and traffic passing between the sites, DNS will need something like [conditional forwarders](https://medium.com/tech-jobs-academy/dns-forwarding-and-conditional-forwarding-f3118bc93984) so each site's local DNS server has a conditional forwarder entry for the remote site's domain, with an entry to query the remote site's DNS server. Then you should have FQDN lookup. Quite what you'd need to do to get short/hostname lookup, I don't know; maybe that would need DNS domain suffixes added to every client?

Comment: Thx, that sounds "logical" - if the ip is known and the routing is setup - routing can apply. To resolve DNS-Queries a Forward-Zone seems to be about right. DCs have static ips, so the forwarding of those queries can directly use the correct route.

Comment: So to sum it up: Client configuration remains the same on both sites. Each "Primary Gateway" is setup with a routing-entry, so it is aware, that "IP-Range XY" has to be accessed through the secondary gateway. Finally, the DCs are configured with a forwarding zone, so DNS resolution is performed correctly by using the defined routing-table in order to access the DCs/DNS Server on the other site?

Comment: (well, ofc, the clients will not directly talk to the DNS on the other site, but the DNS on the same site will query the foreign DNS to resolve IPs on the other site)